# There are a few things in the Developer Story setup that don't seem quite right

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

For reference:

My Developer Story: https://stackoverflow.com/story/thomasjowens

My Developer CV: https://stackoverflow.com/cv/thomasjowens

---

When selecting the network sites to display, it lists meta sites. With the exception of Meta Stack Exchange, I'm not sure why anyone would want to explicitly advertise their Meta presence. This is especially true since reputation-wise, it's tied to the main parent site. Having these other sites makes it harder to scroll through the list. At least by default, Meta sites (except for Meta Stack Exchange) should be hidden to make it easier to navigate and browse.

---

The display of the site name only appears on hover of the site's icon. That's not obvious or clear - it should be on hover anywhere in the box with the icon and reputation. It would be better if the site name was just displayed so it was even more obvious to readers who (1) don't know the SE site logos and (2) don't think to hover over them.

The displays of sites and reputations should also be links to the person's profile on those sites, to give readers easy access to their profile and then to their questions and answers on a given site.

---

On my CV, I used to have my Top n% tags hidden, but it doesn't look like you can hide them anymore, either on the Developer Story or the CV. Yes, those are my top tags on Stack Overflow, but they don't properly represent the bulk of my knowledge or interest, since they are only SO. I'm in the Top 10% of the agile tag on SO and Top 5% for architecture, design, and database-design, again on SO. But this is a Developer Story and my contributions on other development-related sites in development-related tags are just as important. Just looking at Programmers, I'm the third all-time user in agile and scrum, the top all-time user in uml, the 12th user in project-management, the second user in requirements...and so on.

There are other professional or software development related sites I participate on - Project Management, Open Source, The Workplace come to mind. Other people participate on Computer Science, Code Review, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, Law, the list goes on. Users can add top answers from any site in the network, but the Top n% tags appear to only be pulled from Stack Overflow. This feature should be either (1) more inclusive or (2) able to be turned off so it doesn't give readers a false impression.

---

Some of the ordering doesn't make much sense.

It looks like the timeline is supposed to be reverse chronology. However, looking at my timeline in the story view, my IEEE Certified Software Development Associate appears above (meaning after) my position as Senior Software Engineer at UTC Aerospace Systems. A Coursera course that I added appears before my Senior Software Engineer at UTC Aerospace Systems role, but I completed it in 2013, 2 years after I started that position.

I think that positions should appear where you started them. It looks like it appears closer to where it ends. Although I'd be open to the ability to toggle or reorder, since some people may want the positions to appear where they end.

---

You still can't add text descriptions to certifications.

---

The Recommended reading section looks bland. It looks like the books should have their covers next to the title, but for me, none of them do. The columns is better than the single list in the CV view. I think that either the book covers should be displayed, or that image removed to display more titles, since many books listed there have their titles cut off for me.

---

You can still only link to one website, your Twitter, and Github accounts. No room for BitBucket, LinkedIn (although it may be a competitor, it does offer networking and communication that SO Jobs doesn't), email address, Facebook profile, Quora account, Google+, etc. There's just a lot of things that you can't put there that you should be able to.

---

It doesn't apply to me (at the moment, or probably in the near future), but it looks like you can receive job matches unless you put at least 2 technologies that you want to work with. I'm not sure how these fit into job matching, but I'm technology agnostic, so I've left that section empty on the CV. For someone like me who is technology agnostic and doesn't care what they want to work with, listing everything that they can possibly work with would be verbose, to say the least. This should be an optional field, even when using Jobs to find a new job. The technology tags on past positions and education should be sufficient.

Comment: I guess 7 is more than a few. But I don't think it's "many" or "a lot", with respect to the size and scope of Developer Story. Many of these are also on the more minor impact side of things.

Comment: I agree with the ordering complaint. I was confused as to why projects that I started years ago, but don't really have an end date, were appearing above posts that I wrote about those projects years later. Ordering based on start date would make a lot more sense to me.

Comment: @BradLarson You know, that may be it. My certifications are all current. I think that ordering by start date would be better. Although for long running projects, that may also be slightly confusing - projects can be active for a long period of time may be hidden down lower. I'm not sure what the right thing to do here is, from a UX experience. I do know that education, certifications, and work experience should probably be ordered by start date.

Comment: You've brought up a lot of things here. I'll say that we're working through some of the most critical bugs first, then looking at improvements/tweaks/etc. I know that the sorting issue is on the list of things to work on, I'm not certain about everything else... yet.

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah, it's a lot in one post. I started to go through the process of transitioning to the Developer Story and started to notice the problems, so I opened a question here to make notes and comments as I went through it.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to let you know, we've seen this and aren't trying to be silent. :)

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks - I do appreciate it. I did see how many things were tagged with developer-story so quickly after it went out, though, so I'm not surprised it's taking some time to sort through everything and get any big things taken care of.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your detailed feedback.

> When selecting the network sites to display, it lists meta sites. With the exception of Meta Stack Exchange, I'm not sure why anyone would want to explicitly advertise their Meta presence. This is especially true since reputation-wise, it's tied to the main parent site. Having these other sites makes it harder to scroll through the list. At least by default, Meta sites (except for Meta Stack Exchange) should be hidden to make it easier to navigate and browse.

I agree and we’ve removed Meta sites from Developer Story.

> The display of the site name only appears on hover of the site's icon. That's not obvious or clear - it should be on hover anywhere in the box with the icon and reputation. It would be better if the site name was just displayed so it was even more obvious to readers who (1) don't know the SE site logos and (2) don't think to hover over them.
>
> The displays of sites and reputations should also be links to the person's profile on those sites, to give readers easy access to their profile and then to their questions and answers on a given site.

There is certainly more we can do here to make it easier to know which site it is. We’ve added it to our backlog and I’ll update you when we’ve fixed it.

> On my CV, I used to have my Top n% tags hidden, but it doesn't look like you can hide them anymore, either on the Developer Story or the CV. Yes, those are my top tags on Stack Overflow, but they don't properly represent the bulk of my knowledge or interest, since they are only SO. I'm in the Top 10% of the agile tag on SO and Top 5% for architecture, design, and database-design, again on SO. But this is a Developer Story and my contributions on other development-related sites in development-related tags are just as important. Just looking at Programmers, I'm the third all-time user in agile and scrum, the top all-time user in uml, the 12th user in project-management, the second user in requirements...and so on.
>
> There are other professional or software development related sites I participate on - Project Management, Open Source, The Workplace come to mind. Other people participate on Computer Science, Code Review, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, Law, the list goes on. Users can add top answers from any site in the network, but the Top n% tags appear to only be pulled from Stack Overflow. This feature should be either (1) more inclusive or (2) able to be turned off so it doesn't give readers a false impression.

Adding top tags from other sites is an interesting idea. It wouldn’t work in the current design as we group by top percent, regardless of site. We’d also need to make it clearer where the top tags are coming from.

It’s in our backlog as I can see the need for this. I’ll keep you updated on priority.

> Some of the ordering doesn't make much sense.
>
> It looks like the timeline is supposed to be reverse chronology. However, looking at my timeline in the story view, my IEEE Certified Software Development Associate appears above (meaning after) my position as Senior Software Engineer at UTC Aerospace Systems. A Coursera course that I added appears before my Senior Software Engineer at UTC Aerospace Systems role, but I completed it in 2013, 2 years after I started that position.
>
> I think that positions should appear where you started them. It looks like it appears closer to where it ends. Although I'd be open to the ability to toggle or reorder, since some people may want the positions to appear where they end.

Better sorting of items is something we’re currently looking into. We may move to a custom sort where users can choose the order that’s best for them. We’re currently making improvements to the current ordering and will take your example into consideration.

> You still can't add text descriptions to certifications.

We’re looking into improvements to the items and with the aim of giving more flexibility for users to add images, descriptions and links to all items. I’ll keep you updated with the priority of this.

> The Recommended reading section looks bland. It looks like the books should have their covers next to the title, but for me, none of them do. The columns is better than the single list in the CV view. I think that either the book covers should be displayed, or that image removed to display more titles, since many books listed there have their titles cut off for me.

We have some work to do on the Book Covers and [it’s on the list of things to get to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336259/how-do-i-get-book-covers-displayed-for-the-developer-story). We’re working on other higher priority bug fixes, but this will be added to the backlog.

> You can still only link to one website, your Twitter, and Github accounts. No room for BitBucket, LinkedIn (although it may be a competitor, it does offer networking and communication that SO Jobs doesn't), email address, Facebook profile, Quora account, Google+, etc. There's just a lot of things that you can't put there that you should be able to.

Again, another interesting idea. We don’t have any plans to add additional contact info, but we may look as this again if we see the demand.

> It doesn't apply to me (at the moment, or probably in the near future), but it looks like you can receive job matches unless you put at least 2 technologies that you want to work with. I'm not sure how these fit into job matching, but I'm technology agnostic, so I've left that section empty on the CV. For someone like me who is technology agnostic and doesn't care what they want to work with, listing everything that they can possibly work with would be verbose, to say the least. This should be an optional field, even when using Jobs to find a new job. The technology tags on past positions and education should be sufficient.

We’re currently reviewing the data we need in order to match candidates and employers. This will likely result in changes to Developer Story. We're always tweaking how candidates are matched to jobs and we'll pass this feedback along to the team.

Comment: Thank you! I'm liking the overall idea of Developer Story. Can't wait for it to be even more polished.