# In Developer Stories, jobs shouldn't be displayed as points in time

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, developer-story

In contrary to top-answers/certifications/etc., I find quite irrelevant that jobs/educations/etc. are displayed as points in time, one-off events. I believe they should be displayed as periods, durations. Note that I have absolutely no idea how to do though, UX brains needed :)

Comment: They could do it like Facebook, rather than showing the durations, show the start/end dates.

Comment: It seems silly that the projects from a job look like they happened before the job.

Comment: I think it should at least show the balloon on the start date, same for projects.

Comment: Same for education too...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336030/1157054 (See "Some of the ordering doesn't make much sense")

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We're currently reviewing how we can make the timeline easier to read and digest. This feedback will be taken into account.

Comment: This is a good request, and when we are able to spend more time on developer stories it will hopefully be included. But not happening any time soon due to the allocations of dev time being planned. So moving it from [tag:status-review] to [tag:status-deferred]