# Developer story - move up or down items manually

Tags: discussion, developer-story

I believe it would be helpful to have ability to move up or down items manually.

Here my story:

[image]

And here I would like move down my job experience from Mar 2012 under my contribution Aug 2015, Jul 2015, etc. Because now for me it looks messy...

Comment: Your job experience is placed by its end date, not the start date.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yes, i know. But i would like to place it by start date. Or move item manually to desired position.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336245/1157054 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336030/1157054

Entries should really be sorted by start date, not end date. As is it looks like long-running entries (like my jobs and open source projects) happened long after various questions I answered and articles I read related to those projects.